# How to use global array var in Kotlin (android)

Tags: android, list, android-studio, kotlin

I am an old programmer and totally new to android and Kotlin (and anything invented in this century btw)

I am trying to create a simple app for my android box which navigates through a list of urls with the bundled remote control, but I really don't know how to make this list of url because I don't know how Kotlin handles an array.

I found lot of documentation online, but basically I totally miss the basics.

Anyway, I don't really want to learn everything, just how to create a globally accessible list of "channels" by index.
I report my code until now:

```
package com.dm.tutorialwebview

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.Menu
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var webview: WebView? = null
    data class Channel(val number: Int, val name:String, val url: String )
    val channelsList: MutableList<Channel> = mutableListOf()
    var curChannel: Int = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        channelsList.add(1,Channel(1,"channel 1","https://...3"))
        channelsList.add(2,Channel(2,"channel 2","https://..."))
        channelsList.add(3,Channel(3,"channel 3","https://..."))
        channelsList.add(4,Channel(4,"channel 4","https://...u8"))
        channelsList.add(5,Channel(5,"channel 5","https://...u8"))

        webview = findViewById(R.id.myweb)
        webview!!.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webview!!.settings.javaScriptEnabled = false
        webview!!.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        webview!!.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webview!!.settings.builtInZoomControls = false     // abilita comandi zoom
        webview!!.settings.setSupportZoom(false)           // abilita  zoom
        webview!!.overScrollMode = WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
        webview!!.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webview!!.setInitialScale(1)

        curChannel = 1
        webview!!.loadUrl(channelsList[curChannel].url)

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; questo aggiunge elementi alla barra delle azioni se è presente.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)

        for (i in 0 until menu.size()) menu.getItem(i).isVisible = false
        return true
    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_UP -> {
                if (curChannel == 5) return true
                curChannel++
                webview!!.loadUrl(channelsList[curChannel].url)
                true
            }
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN -> {
                if (curChannel == 1) return true
                curChannel--
                webview!!.loadUrl(channelsList[curChannel].url)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
        }
    }


}
```

Unfortunately the app seem to crash on Add method.

I know this is something very simple, but still I have troubles in understanding how this works

i need some hints on fixing declaration and population of "channelsList"

Sorry if I did something wrong in this post, this is the first one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `Unfortunately the app seem to crash on Add method` arrays and lists start at index 0 in kotlin, but you are trying to add the first element at index 1, you don't need to use an index at all if you want to add an item to the end of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a companion object as mentioned in the answer by Kamil Jeglokowski or make a simple object as a ChannelListHolder and a few methods as you prefer, but here is a very simple sample that can get you rolling.

```kotlin
object ChannelListHolder {
    private val list = mutableListOf<Channel>()

    fun addItems(vararg items: Channel) {
        list.addAll(items)
    }

    fun addItem(item: Channel) {
        list.add(item)
    }

    fun removeAll() {
        list.clear()
    }

    fun removeItem(item: Channel) = list.remove(item)

    fun getChannels(): List<Channel> = list
}

fun main() {
    val channels = ChannelListHolder.getChannels()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use Companion object and put your list there

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

```
    companion object {
        val channelList = listOf<Channel>(
            Channel(1, "channel 1", "https://...3"),
            Channel(2, "channel 2", "https://..."),
            Channel(3, "channel 3", "https://..."),
            Channel(4, "channel 4", "https://...u8"),
            Channel(5, "channel 5", "https://...u8")
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please make me an example? How can I change declaration of my list in order to populate it in a function and access it in another?